# some issus about dok_matrix for sparse storeage

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

Now i have eighty million rows,six hundred thousands columns,and 500 millions values are non-zeros.It is sparse.I choose the scipy api dok_matrix to store it .And what 's memory when using dok_matrix,does it seemds not only store non-zeros.

I have 500 millions non-zero values ,but out of memory,why?

```
a = ss.dok_matrix((8000000,600000))

dict1={}
dict2={}
index1=0
index2=0
for line in open("./data"):
        line = line.strip()
        fields = line.split("\t")
        if len(fields)<3:
                continue
        key1 = fields[0]
        key2 = fields[1]
        value = float(fields[2])
        if key1 not in dict1:
                dict1[key1] = index1
                index1 += 1
        if key2 not in dict2:
                dict2[key2] = index2
                index2 += 1
        a[dict1[key1],dict2[key2]] = value
        print ("ok")


b = a.getrow(0).items()
for i in b:
        print (i[0][1],i[1])
```

In my opinion,it requires only non-zeros,10 billion =1G,so it should not oom.And for this case ,how can i store the large sparse feautes?

Comment: `dok` is a subclass of python `dict`.  That's not a compact memory efficient storage.

Answer (score 1):

I'll take your numbers as a given. You construct your matrix as,

```
a = ss.dok_matrix((8000000,600000))
```

This [defaults to `dtype='d'`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.dok_matrix.html), a double-precision floating point number. I will assume this takes 64 bits of memory for its representation (an assumption that is, I think, reasonable). A dictionary-of-keys matrix also *must* store an index for each non-zero value, of which you have some 500 million. That implies we store at least another two integers, for the row and column indices. For simplicity, assume those too take a 64-bit representation.

This leads to the conclusion that each non-zero entry takes some `3 * 64 = 192` bits of memory, or 24 bytes. At 500 million records, that adds up to some  `500 * 10 ** 6 * 24 = 12 * 10 ** 9` bytes, or a little under 12GB in total. Depending on your machine, this may well exceed what is available.

Depending on what you want to do with this matrix, you may be able to load the rows in as batches, processing say a few million rows at a time. This is a common scenario in e.g. training models, as most machines are unable to fit the entire data set into memory all at once. For some more on this, you may have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51911416/python-3-6-deal-with-memoryerror/51911455#51911455).

Answer (score 0):

A `csr` format matrix with your sepifications will require:

```
8000001 int64 array for the indptr attribute
500,000,000 int64 array for the indices attribute
500,000,000 int64 or float64 (possibly 32 instead) for the data attribute
```

The usual way of creating such a matrix is with `coo` format, where the `row` attribute will be of size 500,000,000 (instead of the indptr).

You could construct these arrays with list apppend:

```
row.append(key1)
col.append(key2)
data.append(value)
```

`np.array(row)` etc will be more compact than the list, but isn't good for iterative construction.

A quick way to test whether you can make such a matrix is with:

```
M = sparse.random(8000000,600000, .0001, 'csr')
```

That is make a random csr matrix with these dimensions, and sparisty that roughly generates the 500 million nonzero values.

Comment: how stranged it crashed.The machine memory is 128GB, 10 billion is only 1G,so why it happend>